# Apple sign in not linking with google and email sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase, apple-sign-in

I have a flutter app where users can sign in using email, gmail or apple sign in, the gmail and email successfully link but when I try to Sign in with Apple using an Apple ID with the exact same email address it creates a new user rather than linking to the account,so it also creates a new user in the users collection which I don't want, as an added question is there any way to get the email address of someone who signed in with apple as this is important information for a booking app

my code:

```
//Sign In with Email
  Future signIn({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      final credential =
          EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);
      linkAccount(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future signInWithApple() async {
    final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();

    //google is sign in with credential and apple is signin with provider
    final authResult =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);

    // Create a Firestore document for the user under the 'users' collection
    if (authResult.user != null) {
      await createCollectionForUser(authResult.user!.uid, "apple@gmail.com");

      linkAppleAccount(authResult.user!.uid);
    }
  }

  Future<void> linkAppleAccount(String appleUID) async {
    try {
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

      // Link the accounts based on Apple UID
      await user?.linkWithCredential(
        AuthCredential(
          providerId: 'apple.com',
          signInMethod: 'oauth',
          // Use the Apple UID as the unique identifier
          accessToken: null, // Provide the necessary credentials
        ),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "provider-already-linked":
          print("The provider has already been linked to the user.");
          break;
        case "invalid-credential":
          print("The provider's credential is not valid.");
          break;
        case "credential-already-in-use":
          print("The account corresponding to the credential already exists, "
              "or is already linked to a Firebase User.");
          break;
        // See the API reference for the full list of error codes.
        default:
          print("Unknown error.");
      }
    }
  }

  Future linkAccount(AuthCredential credential) async {
    try {
      final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
          ?.linkWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "provider-already-linked":
          print("The provider has already been linked to the user.");
          break;
        case "invalid-credential":
          print("The provider's credential is not valid.");
          break;
        case "credential-already-in-use":
          print("The account corresponding to the credential already exists, "
              "or is already linked to a Firebase User.");
          break;
        // See the API reference for the full list of error codes.
        default:
          print("Unknown error.");
      }
    }
  }

  /* Future linkAppleAccount(AppleAuthProvider credential) async {
    try {
      final userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.linkWithProvider(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "provider-already-linked":
          print("The provider has already been linked to the user.");
          break;
        case "invalid-credential":
          print("The provider's credential is not valid.");
          break;
        case "credential-already-in-use":
          print("The account corresponding to the credential already exists, "
              "or is already linked to a Firebase User.");
          break;
        // See the API reference for the full list of error codes.
        default:
          print("Unknown error.");
      }
    }
  }*/

  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );

    // Sign in with the credential
    final authResult =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    // Create a Firestore document for the user under the 'users' collection
    if (authResult.user != null) {
      await createCollectionForUser(
          authResult.user!.uid, authResult.user!.email!);

      linkAccount(credential);
    }
  }

//sending verification email to user
  Future sendVerificationEmail() async {
    try {
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      await user.sendEmailVerification();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  User? getUserEmail() {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return user;
  }

  // Function to create a new user using FirebaseAuth and create a collection for the user in Firestore
  Future<void> createUserAndCollectionInFirestore(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      // User created successfully, now create a Firestore collection for the user
      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        await createCollectionForUser(user.uid, user.email!);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating user: $e');
      // Handle the error as needed
    }
  }

  Future<void> createCollectionForUser(String uid, String uemail) async {
    try {
      // Access the Firestore collection for the user and create a new document with the UID as the document ID
      CollectionReference userCollection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

      await userCollection
          .doc(uid)
          .set(<String, dynamic>{'userType': 'member', 'email': uemail});
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating user collection in Firestore: $e');
      // Handle the error as needed
    }
  }

  Future<String?> getUserData(String uid) async {
    try {
      // Access the Firestore collection for the user and get the document with the UID as the document ID
      DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();

      // Get the 'userType' field from the document
      String? userType = userSnapshot.get('userType');
      return userType;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting user data from Firestore: $e');
      // Handle the error as needed
      return null;
    }
  }
```